# C# checkBox_CheckedChanged Referencing in different files

Tags: c#, forms, wpf-controls, checkbox

**Requirement:** I have a windows application written in C# and I'm trying to add a checkbox to it where if it is checked, than the files from the search will be copied into subdirectories based on zip code.

**Problem:** When I reference addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true) from MainForm.cs on a different page SearchProcess.cs I get the error: "addzipdir_checkBox does not exist in the current context". What is the proper way to reference the checkBox_CheckedChanged occurence?

Here's the code on MainForm.cs:

```
    private void addzipdir_checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true))
        {
           Log("Organize files by zip code.");
        }

        if (addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(false))
        {
           Log("Don't Organize files by zip code.");
        }
    }
```

Here's the code on SearchProcess.cs generating an error:

```
        if (addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true))
        {

            // adds the given lead's agentid and zip code to the targetpath string 
            string targetzipdir = m_sc.get_TargetPath() + "\\" + AgentID + "\\" + ZIP;

            // If the given lead's zip code subdirectory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetzipdir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetzipdir);
            }

            targetFileAndPath = m_sc.get_TargetPath() + "\\" + AgentID + "\\" + ZIP + "\\" + fullFileName;
        }   // end if addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true)
```

Comment: I believe checking the box should update a variable somewhere so that you can reference the variable and not the control which is on a different form.

Comment: I added the line bool addzipdirectory_checkbox=1; under the first if statement, if (addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true)) but i still couldn't reference it in the searchprocess.cs file. should i use the invoke statement to bring it in like this m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on State: " + m_sc.get_State() }); or             if (m_sc.get_SearchAND()==true)
            {
                m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search for All" });
            } or bring it in from the Utility.Properties.Settings.Default. area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you right click a variable and click "Go To Definition" it's a lot easier to find where the variable is referenced. I right clicked another variable that was called in through the MainForm and found that they were all called through the SearchCriteria file. I had to bring the addzipdir_checkbox value referenced on the MainForm.cs file through the SearchCriteria.cs file and then call it in the SearchProcess.cs file.

Here's my code on the SearchCriteria.cs file:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    private String Corp;
    private String OrderNumber;
    private String Campaign;
    private String City;
    private String State;
    private String Zip;
    private String SourcePath;
    private String TargetPath;
    private bool SearchOR;
    private bool SearchAND;
    private bool addzipdirectory_checkBox;

    public SearchCriteria()
    {
    }

    public SearchCriteria(String Corp,
                          String OrderNumber,
                          String Campaign,
                          String City,
                          String State,
                          String Zip,
                          String SourcePath,
                          String TargetPath,
                          bool SearchOR,
                          bool SearchAND,
                          bool addzipdirectory_checkBox)              
    {
        this.Corp = Corp;
        this.OrderNumber = OrderNumber;
        this.Campaign = Campaign;
        this.City = City;
        this.State = State;
        this.Zip = Zip;
        this.SourcePath = SourcePath;
        this.TargetPath = TargetPath;
        this.SearchOR = SearchOR;
        this.SearchAND = SearchAND;
        this.addzipdirectory_checkBox = addzipdirectory_checkBox;
    }
    public bool get_addzipdir_checkBox()
    {
        return addzipdirectory_checkBox;
    }
    public void set_addzipdir_checkBox(bool x)
    {
        addzipdirectory_checkBox = x;
    }
}
```

Here's my code on the Searchprocess.cs file:

```
            // Copy the file if ANY of the search criteria have been met
            if (found)
            {

                m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] {"FOUND: Order_No: " + Order_No +
                                                                        " barcode: " + barcode +
                                                                        " MailerCode: " + MailerCode +
                                                                        " AgentID: " + AgentID +
                                                                        " City: " + City +
                                                                        " State: " + State +
                                                                        " ZIP: " + ZIP});


                //passes values to TransferFile 
                TransferFile(directory, barcode, AgentID, ZIP);
            }
        } // end for that finds each matching record 

    }

    // find and copy the file to the target directory string ZIP
    private void TransferFile(string sourceDir, string filename, string AgentID, string ZIP)
    {
        string fullFileName = filename + ".pdf";
        string fullFileNameAndPath = sourceDir + "\\" + fullFileName;
        string targetFileAndPath;

        if (m_sc.get_addzipdir_checkBox()==true)
        {

            // adds the given lead's agentid and zip code to the targetpath string 
            string targetzipdir = m_sc.get_TargetPath() + "\\" + AgentID + "\\" + ZIP;

            // If the given lead's zip code subdirectory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetzipdir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetzipdir);
            }

            targetFileAndPath = m_sc.get_TargetPath() + "\\" + AgentID + "\\" + ZIP + "\\" + fullFileName;
        }   // end if addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to make sure addzipdir_checkBox is public. For this, you need to use the form editor, select the addzipdir_Checkbox and change the property grid 'Modifiers' item to `public` or `internal`.
- Then, you need to find a way to reference the instance of this form, something like this:

  if (myForm.addzipdir_checkBox.Equals(true))
  {
     ...
     ...
  }

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made the modifier property public for addzipdir_Checkbox but when I added if (m_form.addzipdir_checkbox() = 1) I get the error: MainForm doesn't contain definition for addzipdir_checkbox and no extension method addzipdir_Checkbox (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?). I also tried putting if (m_form.get_addzipdir_checkbox() = 1) and that came up with the same error.

Comment: My MainForm file is using the following: using System; using System.ComponentModel; using System.Drawing; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms; using System.Threading; ---------------------------------- and SearchProcess is using the following: using System; using System.Windows.Forms; using System.Threading; using Com.StellmanGreene.CSVReader; using System.IO; using System.Data; using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: @Brian - what's the type of checkbox? Maybe you want to do something like 'if (m_form.addzipdir_checkbox.Checked) {...}' ?

Comment: that didn't work either. it still doesnt recognize the addzipdir_checkbox value. how do i look up the checkbox type?